# Forking to another file causes EADDRINUSE?

Tags: node.js, child-process, httpserver

I have a file called **client.js** that `require("child_process").fork()`s to **source.js**, just to make everything cleaner. However, somewhere in the fork, it is executing another process and causing the `EADDRINUSE` error when I create a `http` server using `connect`. How can I fix this so I can create a `http` server without erroring?

My source.js looks like (somewhat) this:

```
app.use(serve(cwd));
app.use(function(req, res){ // code });

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(8080);
server.on("listening", function(){
    console.log("server running with: ");
    console.log("  port: "+process.env.PORT);
});
```

Comment: `EADDRINUSE` means that there's something already listening on a particular TCP port, so the short answer would be: _"don't use an already-used TCP port"_. The long answer depends on what exactly it is you're trying to do, which your question doesn't elaborate on.

Comment: It's not clear from the question why you're trying to fork, but assuming you're going after scalability, check out the `cluster` module, it makes that sort of thing more well managed.

Comment: @Paul cluster is giving me heck on my IDE, is there a better option?

Comment: What IDE and what kind of "heck"?

Comment: Cloud9, I found a tutorial on a site and ran it and it still gives me `EADDRINUSE`

Answer (score 1):

At system level, fork() is kinda something like:

1. Calculate the memory for the current (parent) process
2. Reserve this size in memory
3. Copy the whole process including, but not limited too:

   - states
   - open fd's
   - open sockets
   - etc
4. If and only if the above step returned non error, then clean this
   memory and use it to launch the forked child, maintaining a comm
   channel with the parent

So, on step 3 fork tries to open AGAIN your listening port, that's why you get the error

A traditional solution probably will be forking before executing server 
listen, but in node sense, in theory there shouldn't be any reason to fork in the first place, even less if you're forking another "node" process.

Probably you could solve it using some kind of async call(), or depending your node version, even use Promises

Comment: I'm calling the listen after the fork() is called.

Comment: And I thought the whole reason of fork() was to make development cleaner. Is there an alternative I should use?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you source.js is doing. Can't give you a generic answer

Comment: It's over 80+ lines. I can put where it's erroring.

Comment: In what way does forking make development cleaner?

Comment: So you already  have a server running and fork() to start another server ? In my opinion you should really forget it. Node way is not to fork. And i can only think in ONE way that forking is useful, but it's not your scenario